# Creating a list of lists passed as arguments to the function in LISP

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a code in LISP where I am taking 3 different lists from user as arguments to my function and then I want to create a new list of these lists.. I tried simple coding but it's not giving me desired output.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
(defun demo(n1 n2 n3)
  (setq list1 '(n1 n2 n3))
  (print list1))

CL-USER 12 : 5 > (demo '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
(N1 N2 N3) 
(N1 N2 N3)
```

When I run this code, instead of giving list of lists it's giving me the output:

```
(n1 n2 n3)
```

desired output is

```
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))
```

Comment: This function exists already. It is called `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a literal list because you're quoting it. You need to refer to the variables in a function call to create a new list.

```
(defun demo (n1 n2 n3)
  (let ((list1 (list n1 n2 n3)))
    (print list1)))
```

You could also use backquote:

```
(defun demo (n1 n2 n3)
  (let ((list1 `(,n1 ,n2 ,n3)))
    (print list1)))
```

You should also use `let` to bind local variables, rather than assigning a global variable with `setq`.

Comment: why do you give the option to use backquote if you need to evaluate every element? I believe that for an OP that does not yet know the concept of quoting this could be confusing.

Comment: I was just showing different ways to do things. Backquote is useful because it allows you to present your data structure in code similarly to the way you view the literal list.